# A $\mathcal{C}^{1}$ differentiable domain and Hausdorff dimension estimates

Tags: general-topology, analysis, geometric-measure-theory, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let us consider an open connected domain $E\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and fix a point $x_0\in\partial E$ on its boundary.
Suppose now, that there exists $R>0$ such that the set $\partial E \cap B_{R}(x_0)$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, i.e. there exists a unique continuous normal vector
\begin{eqnarray*}
\nu \,\colon \,\,& B_{R}(x_0)\cap \partial E&\to &\mathbb{R}^N\\
& x&\mapsto &  \nu_{x}
\end{eqnarray*}
to the set $\partial E\cap B_{R}(x_0)$. The question is: is it true that the set $\partial E$ is $F_\sigma$ and there exists some estimate on the Hausdorff dimension of $\partial E$?

Comment: Do you only have this condition for one specific point $x_0$ on the boundary? That would certainly not imply much about the rest of the boundary. However, every boundary is closed, so it is certainly $F_\sigma$.

Comment: Crossposted http://mathoverflow.net/questions/227187/a-mathcalc1-domain-and-hausdorff-dimension-estimate

Answer (score 0):

Being a codimension 1 smooth submanifold, your set $\partial E\cap B_R(x_0)$ will have Hausdorff dimension $N-1$. The same goes for $\partial E$ since you can take compact sets $K$ and obtain Hausdorff dimension $N-1$ for each intersection $\partial E\cap K$ (by taking a finite subcover by balls $B_{R_i}(x_i)$). Finally, take an increasing sequence of compact sets $K_n$ with $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty K_n=\mathbb R^N$ and note that $$\dim_H \partial E=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dim_H(\partial E\cap K_n)=N-1.$$

Comment: You could make this a community wiki, to not get points twice...

Comment: When you are about to post an answer, there is a little box you can check on the bottom right of where you write the text. It makes the answer a "community wiki written by John B", the answer stays yours but you don't get points for the upvotes it gets. Example (from MO): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/358/examples-of-great-mathematical-writing/

To be honest, I don't know what is the right thing to do (if there's one), I just thought getting points for two identical answers might not be great. :)